# Open source alternative to FME from Safe Software for Spatial ETL?

Tags: open-source-gis, convert, fme-form, spatial-etl

Just wondering if there is any open source solution which comes close to safe FME?
I would like to integrate it into my workflow, but it´s just another few thousand which my employer has to give out for software.

Does anyone know of anything similar?