# Seeking Spatial ETL or some other tools?

Tags: software-recommendations, spatial-etl, geokettle

I need to read geographic data from an ORACLE spatial database in Gauss Boaga SRS, convert them in WSG84 (EPSG 32632), e put them in another ORACLE spatial data base.

I've tried to use GeoKettle 2.5 but I think that there is some bugs because it seems not set SRID on the new geometries.

I need a tool that works on server side and I would not to extract data from the source database, convert them in some intermediate format, to apply the srs conversion and then put the data in the new destination database.

Is there any other open source ETL or some other tool?

Comment: 1. The data format of your geo objects if you request the oracle stuff how does it looks like. 2. Is there a JDBC driver to get the oracle stuff in and out 3. Are there meta formats for geo objects for the oracle db like GML or WKT to clip on an external tool like proj.4?

Comment: Have you tried FME, www.safe.com. They have free trials.

Comment: A couple of other similar questions that may be helpful to you: [Spatial ETL comparisons](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/spatial-etl-comparisons) as well as [Is there any Safe FME alternatives?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24365/is-there-any-safe-fme-alternatives)

Comment: you could use an ogr/gdal python script

Comment: @cesare - do you know if Oracle has a "ST_Transform()" function similar to PostGIS? If so, you can use python with pypyodbc to do this...